# How would be best to compare an element of an array item with a user input

Tags: c#

I'm gathering 3 user inputs which I would want to run against this array and then return the designated information with (there are 2 others but don't want to clog up the question):

```
//variable to hold the return value from readline - set to 0
            int c1 = 0;
            //if that var is 0 go - do while loop - while var = 0  go
            if (c1 == 0)
            {
                while (c1 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a C# Course ID:\n 10 = Basic C# \n 11 = Advanced C# \n 12 = Complex C# \n Only the course ID is valid as an entry");
                    int ID;
                    //Readline - pass variable back for what was entered
                    bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ID);

                    //validation check as to what was entered ; i.e. >=10 <=12
                    if (ID == 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen:\n 10 = Basic C#");
                        c1 = 10;
                    }
                    else if (ID == 11)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen:\n 11 = Advanced C#");
                        c1 = 11;
                    }
                    else if (ID == 12)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You have chosen:\n 12 = Complex C#");
                        c1 = 12;
                    }
                    //if var outside of range, hard set to 0
                    else if (ID >= 10 && ID <= 12)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid input between 10 and 12");
                    }
                }
```

The c1 variable is then ideally put in and run in a foreach loop or something similar in order to pick the correct array item.

```
Courses[] courses =
            {
                //C# Courses which can be chosen- (int courseID, int streamID, string courseName, new DateTime (YYYY/MM/DD))
                new Csharp(10, 1, "Basic C#", new DateTime(2020, 7, 19)),
                new Csharp(11, 2, "Advanced C#", new DateTime(2020, 8, 8)),
                new Csharp(12, 3, "Complex C#", new DateTime(2020, 7, 18)),
                //Java Courses that can be chosen
                new Java(20, 1, "Basic Java", new DateTime(2020, 10, 7)),
                new Java(21, 2, "Advanced Java", new DateTime(2020, 11, 14)),
                new Java(22, 3, "Complex Java", new DateTime(2020, 9, 26)),
                //Netwroking Courses that can be chosen
                new NetWorking(30, 1, "Basic Networking", new DateTime(2020, 12, 29)),
                new NetWorking(31, 2, "Advanced Networking", new DateTime(2021, 1, 15)),
                new NetWorking(32, 3, "Complex Networking", new DateTime(2020, 12, 13))
            };
```

The Courses class is set up like so:

```
public abstract class Courses
    {
        public DateTime CourseDate { get; set; }
        public int StreamID { get; private set; }
        public string CourseName { get; private set; }
        public int CourseID { get; private set; }
        public Courses(int courseID, int streamID, string courseName, DateTime courseDate)
        {
            this.CourseID = courseID;
            this.StreamID = streamID;
            this.CourseName = courseName;
            this.CourseDate = courseDate;
        }
    }
```

The main question is how to compare c1 (user input) against the CourseID (first number in the array item). Once again, thanks in advance, sorry for the many questions!

Comment: `courses` looks like an object array, so of course we'd have to know what that class looks like

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I've edited to include the Courses class structure for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq:

```
var course = courses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CourseID == c1);

if (course == null){
   // No course found
}
```